# How to change the odoo language?

Tags: odoo

I'd like to change the Odoo language, but only the english language is available. Is there any way to add other languages?

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to install the additional languages on the `Settings` menu.

Login as `admin` and make sure you have the `Technical Features` enabled (On user `admin`, `Access Rights` tab, `Technical Features` checkbox).

On the `Settings | Translations | Load a translation` menu option you open a wizard to select and add to your database the language of your choice.